# Automate Powershell Credentials for domain and name changing

Tags: powershell, automation, dns

Heres the code that I have below. Where do i add the Get-Credentials or DomainCredentials to bypass that whole username/password input for these functions?

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

if ($env:computername.contains("A00"))
{
    Write-Host "Computer name:" $env:computername
}else{
    Write-Host "Please enter your desired computer name: [Default $env:computername]:"
    $computername = Read-Host

    $renamecomputer = $true
    $cred = Get-Credential
    if ($computername -eq "" -or $computername -eq $env:computername) { $computername = $env:computername; $renamecomputer = $false }
    $cred = Get-Credential
}

if ($env:USERDOMAIN.contains("CHB"))
{
    Write-Host "Domain name:" $env:USERDOMAIN
}else{
    Write-Host "Adding $computername to the domain"
    Add-Computer -DomainName "domain.local"
    $cred = Get-Credential
    if ($renamecomputer -eq $true) { Rename-Computer -NewName $computername}
    $cred = Get-Credential
}
```

Comment: Didn't get you. What ever code you add, if you want to Add the computer, you need to get credentials. `Get-Credential` prompt for credentials if used.

Comment: where would `Get-Credential` go while trying to change the computer name because i've added it after `if ($computername -eq "" -or $computername -eq $env:computername Get-Credentials $cred)` but theres errors showing.

Comment: `Get-Credentials` is a cmdlet. you can't use as mentioned above. `$Cred = Get-Credentials` in a separate line.

Comment: after inputting `$cred = Get-Credentials` before and after the if statement for renaming and domain it still prompts for the credentials.

Comment: `}else{
    Write-Host "Please enter your desired computer name: [Default $env:computername]:"
    $computername = Read-Host
    $renamecomputer = $true
    $cred = Get-Credential
    if ($computername -eq "" -or $computername -eq $env:computername ) { $computername = $env:computername; $renamecomputer = $false }
    $cred = Get-Credential`

Comment: please update the post rather than posting code in comment

Comment: I have Updated the post

Comment: You are asking for credential from user, but not using it. I would say, please take some time to learn and understand PowerShell. You can start from 
https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start-8276